# What does "You dare not make a mistake!" implies in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It doesn't make sense here saying "You don't have enough courage to make a mistake!" I would have think it means "Try to make a mistake and see what will happen!" as there is a entry in dictionary which is "[with obj. and infinitive] defy or challenge (someone) to do something", but the part of speech is a regular verb whereas in the sentence I provided it's a modal verb.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ***dare*** is a "modal" verb in OP's cited context. It's what's called a...

> **catenative** verb
> *The word **catenative** comes from the Latin **catena** meaning "chain". Catenative verbs combine with other verbs and can form a chain of two or three or more verbs.* [<sub>(englishclub.com)</sub>](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-catenative.php)

> A main verb (ie **lexical verb**, not **auxiliary** or **modal**) that can be followed by another main verb is known as a catenative verb. In the following examples, the verbs **want** and **like** are catenative:
> *I want to eat.*
> *I like eating.*

---

As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t%20dare%20go%2Cdon%27t%20dare%20to%20go&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20dare%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20dare%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20dare%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20dare%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0) shows, ***dare*** is one of a small number of verbs that can *(optionally)* be followed by a "bare infinitive" (without the infinitive marker ***to***)...

[image]

Other catenative verbs that don't need ***to*** include ***hear, help, let, make***, as described [here](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-catenative.php). Note that *Don't you **dare** [to] be late!* is like *He **helped** [to] wash the dishes* or *He **makes** me [to] [lie down in green pastures](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=makes%20me%20to%20lie%20down%2Cmakes%20me%20lie%20down&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmakes%20me%20to%20lie%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmakes%20me%20lie%20down%3B%2Cc0)*, in that the word ***to*** is effectively "optional" in such constructions. But with almost all other verbs used catenatively, ***to*** is syntactically *required*.

---

That's all the syntactic background. For the specific context here, *You dare not make a mistake* is alternative phrasing for the imperative command *You must not dare [to] make a mistake* - effectively, *Don't be so "brave" as to make a mistake (because the consequences would be dire)*. But of course, what we actually *understand* from that is...

> *Don't be so **carelessly foolish** as to make a mistake!*

Comment: After a lot of consideration, I realize that since the word "dare" can take "not" directly, the sentence "You dare not make a mistake![1]" is actually a imperative. The subject "you" is merely a intensifier. It's the same when saying "Dare not make a mistake!" Plus the idiomatic expression "don't you dare", the sentence easily becomes "Don't you dare make a mistake!"[2] So these two sentences[1][2] are different ways of saying the same thing, am I right? I think I misunderstood the original sentence by simple present declarative due to the unusual usage of "dare".

Comment: The causative _make_ can, optionally, take the infinitive marker **to**? I find that claim dubious. The consensus emerging from [this ELU discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441778/make-somebody-to-do-something) seems to suggest if the infinitive marker __to__ occurs it is not a causative _make_.

Comment: @EddieKal: I added a link to my "green pastures" biblical example (as a child I learnt the archaic version ***maketh** me to lie down*). I don't deny that most people *today* wouldn't include the infinitive marker with "causitive make", but having just checked out your ELU "discussion" lnk I think it's mostly at best irrelevant, if not downright misleading. The gist of the relevant full OED entry seems to be that *make **to** verb* fell out of use after C17 *except with passive constructions*. So *She was made to scrub floors* is perfectly okay (and doesn't mean that was her purpose in life).

Comment: @preachers: I don't think any native speaker would utter the command *Dare not make a mistake!* Feasibly *Don't dare make a mistake!*, but the vast majority would include the addressee pronoun in *Don't you dare [to] [do something]!* I'm not sure why that is, given that for *most* imperative constructions we *don't* explicitly include ***you*** (whether negated or not).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Thanks for your explanation. There is still one last thing, if we take "You dare not make a mistake!" as a singleton without considering the context it's in. Can we understand the same sentence to have two completely different meanings? One being the imperative mood meaning "to discourage you to make a mistake" and the other one being a regular declarative simple present sentence meaning "you don't have enough courage to make a mistake".

Comment: No. A native speaker probably *wouldn't* say *You dare not make a mistake!* if what he meant was *You don't have enough courage to make a mistake*. To intend that meaning would require a very different context anyway (advising some ultra-cautious would-be entrepreneur that he's doomed to fail in the long run because he's unwilling to take risks that will sometimes lead to short term setbacks, perhaps). But that's a fairly subtle point to make, so it would probably have to be expressed using more care *and more words*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica [Here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dare_1) is the entry in Oxford Learner's Dictionary. In entry 1 it says "to be brave enough to do something" and one of the examples below is "They daren't ask for any more money." which is logically the same as "You dare not make a mistake!"

Comment: That's all perfectly true, but we're dealing with a highly specific idiomatic usage here *(Don't you dare touch me!)* where the concept of "bravery" isn't really relevant. It's more along the lines of *Don't even **think about** touching me! [or I'll kill you, you children, and your children's children...]* Note that [*Don't you dare {ask}*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=daren%27t+ask+for%2Cdon%27t+dare+ask+for%2Cdon%27t+you+dare+ask&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) is still idiomatically current, but those other usages are in decline.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Well, I have to say, yeah, I've got your idea and understood that _You dare not make a mistake!_ is semantically identical to the imperative _Don't you dare make a mistake!_. What I'm asking now is kinda a different question which is focus on the sentence itself without considering the context. I'm wondering if the sentence _You dare not make a mistake!_ itself has the meaning of _You don't have enough courage to make a mistake._ and has the same syntax logic like the example _They daren't ask for any more money._ in Oxford Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it means "don't you dare make a mistake!" meaning that he must not make a mistake.

Comment: So what's the grammatical logic here? How comes a declarative sentence becomes a imperative one?

Comment: *He didn't dare [to] fail* is declarative (reporting a fact), whereas *Don't [you] dare [to] fail!* is always imperative (commanding the addressee).